# How to change a SVG based on browser width?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I am searching for the best way to dynamically change an svg shape based on browser width. Setting the width to 100% stretches the shape to follow the width of the browser, but it also scales or distorts the shape... What I am after: [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVywH.png)

Is it possible to do this with Javascript or is there a better approach? HTML canvas? thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you never want the height of the svg to update, and just have the right side of it stretch to fill the screen?

Comment: Essentially yes... the effect I'm after is used on the shape/background of nav bar of the site inholland.nl  that site uses HTML canvas to achieve that effect, but I was wondering if there was a easier way...

Answer (score 0):

As you're after an alternative approach involving SVGs, here's one. Unfortunately I wouldn't say it's easier than using a canvas though.

Anyway - to be able to stretch one part of a shape independently from the other we actually need to divide that shape in two. That way the left part can remain static.

If we take a look at the shape you're after:
[image]

we can easily see that there's a quarter circle

[image]

and a right trapezoid

[image]

Constructing them using the drawing commands is rather straight-forward - simply putting those side-by-side won't do the job though.

The trick here is to make the quarter circle a fixed-size - e.g. 80 x 80 pixels - and **don't** give the trapezoid a size at all. Instead we need to populate the CSS `background-image` property of a plain `<div>` element with an URL to the shape. This can be done in-line too. To make it stretch to the browser window, we need to make it's width 100% of the remaining space - which can be done by setting the `overflow` property of the element to `hidden`. Now just make the background's height equal to the quarter circle's height and set the `background-repeat` property to `no-repeat`.

Now the browser stretches the background image to whatever the remaining width beside the static quarter circle is and the fixed 80 pixels height.

Here's an example:

```css
.svgB {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 5 5' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='none'><polygon points='0,0 5,0 5,2.5 0,5' style='fill:grey;'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 80px;
}

.svgB>* {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.svgA {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgA">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 5 5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="black" d="M5,5 a5,5 0 0,1 -5,-5 L5,0" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="svgB" style="height:80px;">
  <p>Here's some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes my next idea was to try something like this with the shape cut into two parts. But I guess I wrote my question poorly... After thinking about it some more I searched 'control svg d attribute via javascript' and that delivered results more like I was thinking...(see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977330/how-to-add-a-path-with-d-attributes-to-a-svg-dynamically)  I'm just more familiar with SVG so Was leaning in that direction...

Comment: Any thoughts as ti with approach might be 'better' svg vs. HTML5 canvas? As this is for a nav bar, there need to be elements, inside (or under) (like the inHolland example...)